# Forward declared variable not accessible in cpp file

Tags: c++

Considering the example below:

header.h

```
extern int somevariable;
    
void somefunction();
```

source.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

somevariable = 0; // this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

void somefunction(){
    somevariable = 0; // works fine
}
```

I couldn't find the answer to the following questions:

1. Why can't I just forward declare `int somevariable` and initialize it in the `.cpp` file?
2. Why is the `somefunction()` function able to "see" `somevariable` when declared using `extern int somevariable`, and why is it not accessible outside of a function?

Comment: Between "forward declare" and "initialize", there needs to be the step "define". `extern int somevariable;` says to look elsewhere for a definition of `somevariable`, `somevariable = 0;` assigns a value of `0` to it, but in neither case have you actually provided a definition. If you want the definition to reside in the cpp file, the line would be `int somevariable;`, or `int somevariable = 0;` if you want to define and initialize it together.

Comment: in cpp should be `int somevariable = 0;`

Comment: Do not use global variables! Never. This makes code fragile and hard to maintain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad

Comment: Thanks, I had confusion with forward declaration and definition. Forward declaration is just a "this exists". Only reason to forward declare would be to share the variable outside?

Comment: C++ is not scripting language, so you can't run code from global scope (expect for initializes).

Comment: You can't assign to a variable outside of a function.  You can _initialise_ it, but that's a different thing, and would, perforce, include defining it.  So, what @MarekR says in his first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
extern int somevariable;
```

means definition of `somevariable` is located somewhere else. It is not forward declaration. Forward declaration is used in context of classes and structs.

---

```
somevariable = 0;
```

is invalid since this is assignment and you can't run arbitrary code in global scope.
It should be:

```
int somevariable = 0;
```

and this means define (instantiate) global variable `somevariable` in this translation unit and initialize it to `0`.
Without this statement linking of your program will fail with error something like: `undefined reference to 'somevariable' referenced by ...` .

---

Use of global variable in any langue is considered as [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad), sine as project grows global variable makes code impossible to maintain and bug-prone.

Comment: I understand that global variable is a sin. I used that as an example to make it easier to understand. So I wrote `int somevariable;` in the header file and then `int somevariable = 0;` and I get that it's defined multiple time. I got the header guard to prevent multiple import... why is it happening? I did the test with a `class objA` defined in header1, then in header2 I write `objA instanceA;` and then in the cpp same but I again get the error.